If a person wasn't repentant when they got baptized/confirmed/received the Eucharist, are they a valid Catholic?
If a person wasn't repentant (sorry for their sins and living sinfully still) when they got baptized/confirmed/received the Eucharist in a cathedral but later on they repent (feel sorry for their sins) do all they have to do now is go to confession?  Are they a valid catholic?
Can you cite some sources too if you can please. Thanks.

I think the answer is yes. But that might be an Orthodox and not Catholic understanding.

This requires nuance. First, all that is necessary to become a Catholic strictly speaking is baptism. When infants are baptized, they don't receive the other two sacraments of initiation right away in the Latin Church, though they do in the Eastern Catholic Churches (the ones in full communion with Rome). Infants can't be unrepentant, so they would always receive the full graces of the sacraments received.
After the age of reason, baptism requires the consent of the party being baptized in order for it to be valid. This would mean that someone who is unrepentant at the time of their baptism, but who nonetheless consents to baptism, is still validly baptized. This is because a sacrament is effective ex opere operato, which means from the work worked. It's not the disposition of the minister or of the recipient that determines whether a sacrament works or what it does. For more on how consent affects validity of baptism, see this question.
As long as someone received a valid baptism, they would only need to go to confession for sins committed after the baptism. If someone received confirmation while in a state of sin, they would receive it validly, but would not receive the full graces of the sacrament until they went to confession.
For the Eucharist, reception of the sacrament in the state of mortal sin is itself a mortal sin. This doesn't pertain to whether or not the person is a validly baptized Catholic and has no bearing on whether they are still a Catholic.

As far as I know, receiving Confirmation in  a state of mortal sin is also a mortal sin, just like the Eucharist.

@AndreasBlass I haven't heard of that. I'd be interested in seeing a source on it.

My usual reference for such things is "Moral Theology" by Fr. Heribert Jone.  In Section 463, "Requirements for the lawful reception", the second paragraph says "For the sacraments of the living, the state of grace is a grave obligation." Section 447 defined sacraments of the living to be all the sacraments except baptism and penance, so confirmation is included.
